# Getting into Python API of QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, references

After a few hours I am about to give up on finding a kind of documentation for the QGIS Python API that actually works/gives the correct information. It is obvious that there is no actual code documentation besides the one for the C++ API which differs from what works in Python. Ok, there is the help()-function, too, to get information about classes which is more than ust tedious to use. As an entry point, I thought I could use the tutorials/cookbook: http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#modifying-vector-layers. Even simple things like adding features does not work the described way in the current QGIS Version 2.4.0-Chugiak (there is no addFeature-function for example).

I wonder how working with the Python console and writing plugins makes sense under such unfavorably conditions.

What sources can actually be used to lookup and learn the Python API for QGIS for current versions?