# Seeking learning resources for PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, references

What are some resources for learning PyQGIS?

It would be interesting having a collection of books or websites that provide some practical examples for learning the syntax or accomplishing specific tasks.

Ideally, these resources should give a general guidance for both beginner and experienced users.

[Seeking QGIS user interface tutorials and web resources](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3651) is a very similar question, but it gives help for learning the QGIS user interface rather than PyQGIS.

Answer (score 12):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
> because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
> and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
> should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
> type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
> site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
> to do so by editing this answer.

---

The following resources give a general guidance for learning or using PyQGIS and generally assume a minimum proficiency of working with Python.

---

## QGIS 3.x versions

- [PyQGIS 3 API Documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/): official documentation of the Python API. Documentation for each major release since v3.0 as well as the nightly version is provided;
- [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/): written for QGIS 2.x it is gradually updated to 3.x. It still may be helpful as a tutorial and a reference guide and gives a good overview of the principal functionalities.

---

## QGIS 2.x versions

**PyQGIS Documentation:**

- [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/): official introduction to PyQGIS programming. It is intended to work both as a tutorial and a reference guide and gives a good overview of the principal functionalities;
- [PyQGIS API Documentation](http://geoapis.sourcepole.com/qgispyapi/): inofficial documentation of the Python API by SourcePole. It provides a searchable interface, but was not updated since QGIS 2.8;
- [QGIS C++ API Documentation](http://qgis.org/api/3.10/): official C++ API documentation. While describing the C++ API, it can be useful for pyqgis development.

**Online books:**

- Sherman G. (2018, 2nd ed.). [PyQGIS Programmer's Guide 3](https://locatepress.com/book/ppg3): extending QGIS 3 with Python 3;
- Westra E. (2014). [Building Mapping Applications with QGIS](https://www.amazon.it/Building-Mapping-Applications-QGIS-Sophisticated/dp/178398466X/ref=pd_sim_14_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=35ZDPVBW70A0G69R8D17): for both beginners and experienced Python developers, this book covers a lot of topics about the using of PyQGIS, including the creation of QGIS plugins and the using of QGIS in an external application;
- Lawhead J. (2015). [QGIS Python Programming Cookbook](https://www.amazon.it/QGIS-Python-Programming-Cookbook-Geospatial/dp/1783984988/ref=pd_sim_14_5?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=EGWJDG9WTHF7HMAYX0NF): 140 recipes for learning and automating geospatial workflows;
- Menke K., Richard S., Pirelli L. (2015). [Mastering QGIS](https://www.amazon.it/Mastering-QGis-Practical-Step-step/dp/1784398683/ref=pd_sim_14_5?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=H5229D2PM9JT3RCRZ4PM): some sections provide practical, step-by-step examples for familiarizing with PyQGIS;
- Graser A. (2016). [Learning QGIS - Third Edition](https://www.amazon.it/Learning-QGIS-Third-Anita-Graser/dp/1785880330/ref=pd_sim_14_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=EGWJDG9WTHF7HMAYX0NF): one section is entirely dedicated to scripting QGIS with Python, starting from the basis to a more advanced using of the several available tools;
- Lawhead J. (2017). [QGIS Python Programming Cookbook - Second Edition](https://www.amazon.it/QGIS-Python-Programming-Cookbook-Second/dp/1787124835/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1501074413&sr=8-2&keywords=QGIS%20Python%20Programming%20Cookbook): this book has a complete code upgrade to QGIS 2.18 and 30 new recipes.

**Tutorials / Blogs / Web resources:**

- [Anita Graser]: [PyQGIS 101: Introduction to QGIS Python programming for non-programmers](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/) (tutorial for beginners)
- [Nathan Woodrow](https://nathanw.net/): a blog mostly about QGIS stuff that also treats specific topics about the using of PyQGIS. The author is one of the most active QGIS developers;
- [nyalldawson.net](http://nyalldawson.net/): a blog with several posts about the using of PyQGIS. The author is one of the most active QGIS developers;
- ["How To" in QGIS](https://howtoinqgis.wordpress.com/): the site provides some suggestions for solving problems using PyQGIS. When possible, these tips are offered through simple code samples. I'm the author of this blog;
- [QGIS Tutorials and Tips](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/): a section of this blog provides a series of tutorials for learning PyQGIS scripting. The author is a very experienced GIS specialist;
- [Lutra Consulting](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/categories/pyqgis/index.html): a list of posts, having the PyQGIS tag, that cover some topics about PyQGIS.
- YouTube channel [PyQGIS](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOnU8rXypMvJQ-Z0pl6mC9Q/videos) (dozens of videotutorials about using Python with QGIS - in german only, but the principles should become clear);

---

The following documentation resources should ease your PyQGIS development experience:

A diagram of the main PyQGIS relationships (by Thomas Gratier): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/webgeodatavore/qgis-class-diagram/master/diagramme_principal.png

Searchable documentation of PyQGIS classes (by SourcePole): http://geoapis.sourcepole.com

For example, the `addFeature` method you had problems with is described here:
http://geoapis.sourcepole.com/qgispyapi/qgsvectorlayer#QgsVectorLayer.addFeature

[image]

As a second example, the `setAttribute` method is described here:
http://geoapis.sourcepole.com/qgispyapi/qgsfeature#QgsFeature.setAttribute

[image]

---

Not sure what you mean in [Getting into Python API of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/114301/115), but there is an addFeatures() function of course. This works in QGIS 2.4:

```
mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:4326&field=MYNUM:integer&field=MYTXT:string", "temp_layer", "memory")

if not mem_layer.isValid(): raise Exception("Failed to create memory layer")

mem_layer_provider = mem_layer.dataProvider()

my_polygon = QgsFeature()
my_polygon.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromRect(QgsRectangle(16,48,17,49)))
my_polygon.setAttributes([10,"hello world"])

mem_layer_provider.addFeatures([my_polygon])

mem_layer.updateExtents()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

If you are unhappy with the API docs and the PyQGIS Cookbook, your last chance is to **look into working plugins** - they are open source after all - and you can easily see if they work in 2.4 ...

To improve documentation, the project happily accepts resources of any kind.

---

Another collection for informations about learning PyQGIS: 
http://spatialgalaxy.net/2014/10/18/pyqgis-resources/

---

Here are some urls that might help you:

1. PyQGIS Developer Cookbook https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/
2. QGIS Python API documentation https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.14/